# Vba excel code for conditional combinations

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me solve the following problem.
I currently have the following data in a column in excel

```
(1,2)
(1,5)
(2,6)
(3,4)
(3,12)
(4,6)
(4,9)
(4,11)
(6,10)
(7,9)
(7,11)
```

I want to know how to find all combinations of at least 2 items from the above list where all numbers numbers of the items are unique. For instance,
`{(1,5),(2,6),(3,12),(4,9)}` is a valid combination because all of the numbers in that set are unique while `{(1,5),(2,6),(6,10)}` is not since the 6 is repeated. Please help.

Comment: So find all combinations but reject ones that don't meet your rule?  Seeing your code would help.

Comment: That is exactly what needs to be done. thinking I need to get power set of that set and then reject ones that don't meet rule but that is starting big and reducing. How about starting small and adding?

Comment: The algo would depend on how you're finding permutations.  Likely the most efficient would be to recurse the permulations and terminate any recursion trees as soon as they hit a duplicate in a subset.

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is:

1. Read all the data into an array
2. For each array element, read the data into a variable and remove the parents. Then id separate the data into an array using the split. So 1,2 would be array(1) =1, array(2) = 2.
3. Id then use a dictionary (Scripting dictionary) by adding these data items as the key. That way you can use the Exists function to determine if the data is a duplicate.
4. Repeat for all elements.

You can always store the results in another dictionary or redim preserve a variant array.